Internal error: Error: Expected a suspended thenable. This is a bug in React. Please file an issue. in router.replace("/") in next js 14
I want that after receiving response in fetch api
redirect user to the main page but i have got an  error

Internal error: Error: Expected a suspended thenable. This is a bug in React. Please file an issue. in router.replace("/") in next js 14

await fetch(`/${locale}/api/auth/signup`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 201) {
      Toast.fire({
        title: "Nice...",
        icon: "success",
      }).then(() => {
        router.replace("/");
      });

i want to redirect user  to main page if status code 201

Your first then doesn’t return a promise for the second then to do something with.  Can you put the call to router.replace into the first then?

yes it's working
thank you bro
